# PayPal JAVA REST API: display exception friendly message to user

Tags: java, rest, paypal, message, user-friendly

PayPal JAVA REST API: how to display exception friendly message to user.

The payment exception message like:

```
   Error: java.io.IOException: Response code: 400 Error response: 
{"name":"TRANSACTION_REFUSED","message":"The request was refused.
{0}","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#
TRANSACTION_REFUSED","debug_id":"e4334e766671"}
```

PayPalRESTException does not have API like: getFriendlyMessage().

Thanks.